# Is there a way to use Route 53 as a DNS failover, that activates a dormant (i.e. cheaper) EC2 instance that takes over?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is there a way to use Route 53 as a DNS failover, that activates a dormant (i.e. cheaper) EC2 instance that takes over?

My idea is to use a different provider to host most of the time, but if there is downtime a monitoring service by Route 53 would activate the dormant EC2 instance and route the DNS to that one, until the primary server is available again.

Thoughts?

Better ideas?

Comment: It *should* be possible for a Route 53 health check to trigger a Cloudwatch alarm that triggers a capacity change in an EC2 Auto Scaling group, to start up the EC2 instance, assuming an auto scaling group supports a minimum running instance count of 0.  Have you explored that route?